# H1 extra padding not being removed

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to get rid of the extra padding on my h1 text (space above and below the text), I've tried it all and nothing seems to be working. Any idea why? Here's a simple example, as you can see there's extra space above and below each h1 text.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.some-text {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px blue;
}

.some-text h1 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-text">
  <h1>hello there</h1>
  <h1>cruel world</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: before accepting the answer, try to use letter like `j p q` and see what is happening https://jsfiddle.net/e41jvtqw/

Comment: @TemaniAfif All you would have to do is add padding in between them. His answer solved the extra space issue but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.some-text {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px blue;
}

.some-text h1 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: red;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-text">
  <h1>hello there</h1>
  <h1>cruel world</h1>
</div>
```

The issue is the default `line-height` of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Its not padding or margin, its the default spacing for that font. You can adjust it with `line-height` if needed

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.some-text {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px blue;
}

.some-text h1 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-text">
  <h1>hello there</h1>
  <h1>cruel world</h1>
</div>
```

Line height can also be unit less, so that the new line-height will be

> line-height = calculated `font-size` multiplied by the provided unit
>   less line height.

**Example**

```
line-height: .7;
font-size: 60px
```

In this case the `line-height` will be `60px * .7 = 42px;`

Comment: I didn't see this last part wow thank you man, it's really useful!